# Is it possible do deploy web app with File upload feature in Azure without using File/Blob storage service? Where will the file gets saved

Tags: java, azure, file, wildfly, azure-storage

Background - We have a Java web application running on Wildfly in a Linux box. The app has a file upload feature where the files are saved inside /opt/app/ location.

We are planning to migrate this to Azure. Is it possible do deploy the current app "AS IS" in Azure without using File/Blob storage service? Which Path will the file gets saved & is it possible to access them via VM Terminal?

Else, Is it mandatory (or recommended) to store the files in Azure file storage? This would want us to rewrite the application layer to use Azure File Storage Rest APIs.

Comment: Do you have more concerns? If the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? it would help others. Thanks:).

Comment: Thanks for response. One more question - Is your answer applicable for both PaaS & IaaS approach?

Comment: Yes, applicable for the both.

Answer (score 1):

You can not deploy it "AS IS" in azure.

When you deploy it to azure, it is actually deployed to [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki). In the kudu, it does not have the path like "/opt/app/".

It is just recommended to use Azure file storage for file uploading/storage when you work in azure because it's convenient and cheap. Of course, you can upload file to any places where can be accessed by internet like FTP. And you can also upload the file directly to the kudu(but it's really not recommended, it is especially used for deployment your site).

Anyway, using azure file storage or blob storage is a recommendation you should consider that first.